# Validate input field the second it gets a value

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Using wp's upload function, I've got users able to upload an image, this sends to S3 and returns a url, and input's this into *#imgurl*

*#imgurl* will be a hidden field and I'm trying to get JavaScript to work out once an image has been uploaded to display a message - The problem I have is getting it to check when #imgurl has a value

```
<div class="input-group">
    <label for="imageurl">
    <input type="text" name="imageurl" id="imageurl"  size="36"  placeholder="http://" />
    <input id="imageUpload" class="button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
</div>
```

I thought it could be done with setInterval but I'm a little lost from this point.

I can work out most other stuff with JS but this has stumped me

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(isFieldEmpty, 60000);

function isFieldEmpty() {
  // run field check code here?
  console.log("yes/no");

}
```

Thanks :D

Comment: how you are changing the value of the input?

Comment: @brk it would be a text input, so once a user starts to type, an action is made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
document.getElementById('imageurl').addEventListener('change', function() {
 if (this.value !== this.getAttribute('placeholder')) {
   console.log('The value has changed to ' + this.value);
 }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, while this worked a treat. I ended up doing something much simpler for my problem & can't believe I went down this route.

I wanted to remove fields based on a text field having a value.
I have a media upload that uploads to s3 and injects that URL into the text field.

I simply just added my JS lines after `$('#imageurl').val(attachment.url);` within my image upload function

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
document.getElementById(imgurl).value
```

or `$("#imgurl").val()` in jQuery.